# How can I find all modules using a table/query in MS access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm reverse engineering a convoluted MS Access 2003 database I inherited.

Is there a way to list the names of all modules referencing a table or query?

I would prefer to use VBA and not buy a third party tool.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a way to list each subroutine/function within the module?

Comment: The only possible way to do this would be some compiler or intereper that actually "runs" the code. I mean, dim sTable as string. Then in code we set that string to operate on some table. The VBA code OFTEN does not have the SQL or table name hard coded (exactly why one is using VBA code - heck the code might even prompt the user for what table or query to run which in turn operates on a table. I not aware of ANY developer platform in the last 50 years that can effective accomplish this issue.

Comment: The MZ-Tools global "Find" function gets you a nice overview of all places in all modules where a string is found. This is usually much more helpful than a simple list of modules. But of course Albert's comment still applies - when SQL is built dynamically, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the module names, not the names of the functions or procedures within the module though.

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    MSysNavPaneObjectIDs
WHERE   Type = 32775
```

Comment: How can I specify the table name?  For example, I want to find modules that refer to "tblTest".

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending the MSys SQL query by using an inline VBA function that checks the table name in the string output of module's code:

**VBA** Function *(place this in a standard module)*

```vb
Public Function CheckModules(modulename As String, tblname As String) As Boolean
    Dim strCode As String, linecount As Integer

    linecount = Access.Modules(modulename).CountOfLines
    strCode = Access.Modules(modulename).Lines(1, linecount)

    If strCode Like "*" & tblname & "*" Then
        CheckModules = True
    Else
        CheckModules = False
    End If
End Function
```

**SQL** Query

```sql
SELECT [Name] As ModuleName
  FROM MSysNavPaneObjectIDs
 WHERE Type = 32775 
   AND CheckModules([Name], "tblTest") = True
```

**---CAVEAT---**

In order to effectively run the inline function SQL query, open all modules in VBA IDE prior to running the query and then just easily close all modules. Refrain from running query in Access Query window:

```vb
Dim i As Variant

' OPEN MODULES '    
For Each i In CurrentProject.AllModules
    DoCmd.OpenModule i.Name
Next i

DoCmd.OpenQuery "CheckModulesforTableQ"

' CLOSE MODULES '
For Each i In CurrentProject.AllModules
    DoCmd.Close acModule, i.Name
Next i
```

Comment: Indeed, @HansUp, I add a note for OP to open all modules prior to running query.